# Encontro no FISL

Tags: debate, meetup

Gostaria de saber se há alguém presente no Fórum Internacional de Software Livre, e caso haja, se vocês gostariam de se encontrar pra jogar um pouco de conversa fora. 
Existem vários espaços propicios para isso, só surgerir data (quinta, sexta ou sábado) e hora.

Abraço.

Comment: Ninguém? Vamos lá gente

Comment: Onde e quando é?

Comment: Poste o link e detalhes relevantes do evento. Pode ser que alguém se aventure por lá. :D

Comment: http://softwarelivre.org/fisl16 vai até sábado e acontece aqui em POA.